# Restrict traffic to 2g in android

Tags: android

My intention was to restrict traffic to 2g only but I have been looking long and apart from #*#4636#*# the only thing I got is something about a domestic android APIs that seemed very difficult to reach implement. I tried to create a intent to dial the number but it doesnt work. 
I want to connect my app with the service that I am accessing dialing it but not how to do it.
Any ideas?

Thank you